# New Blazor Web Assembly Project Cannot find appsettings.json

Tags: blazor, .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, appsettings

I'm bulding a simple blazor web assembly app in .net 6. I run the app and I get an error:  **The configuration file 'appsettings.json' was not found and is not optional. The expected physical path was '/appsettings.json'** This is my code in Program.cs:

```
using DataReload.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT");

builder.Configuration.SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddJsonFile(path: "appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                       .AddJsonFile(path: $"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultDatabaseConnection");
builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("ReportDatabaseConnection");
await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

This is my directory:

[image]

Comment: Should `appsettings.json` be in the `wwwroot` folder?

Comment: It's in the same folder as every other blazor app I work on. I'll try moving it there.

Comment: Moved it to wwwroot. Same error.

Comment: According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/21391) you shouldn't need to explicitly load it - if `appsettings.json` or `appsettings.{environmentName}.json` is present in the `wwwroot` folder they will be automatically loaded.